# How to display only one maximum value for date in a MS query table using SQL (not a set of maximum values)?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am attempting to display only one maximum value for a date value (I would like to see only one value in other columns for the newest possible date).

Are there any options how to achieve this in MS Query sql?

My table is this:

[image: MS query sql table]

My current code is this:

```
SELECT stof_0."arti-cd-base", stof_0."dcmf-nr", Max(stof_0."stof-dt") AS 'Maximum z stof-dt', stof_0."stof-qty-op"
FROM NILOS.PUB.stof stof_0

GROUP BY stof_0."arti-cd-base", stof_0."dcmf-nr", stof_0."stof-qty-op", stof_0."arti-cd-sfx", stof_0."adfc-cd-diffco"

HAVING (stof_0."arti-cd-base"=1) AND (stof_0."arti-cd-sfx"=15) AND (stof_0."adfc-cd-diffco"=0)

ORDER BY stof_0."arti-cd-base", Max(stof_0."stof-dt") DESC
```

Would anyone know how to arrange the code so that only one value (one line) will be the result for the latest date in the table?

Comment: Most people here want sample table data and also the expected result as formatted text, i.e. not as images.

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server?

Comment: Its an MS Query openned via MS Excel and it uses SQL commands

Comment: Please consider an oracle database with SQL - if you asked about this

Answer (score 0):

If you just one one row with the latest date in the table use `order by` and some form of limiting the results.  In standard SQL, you can do:

```
select s.*
from NILOS.PUB.stof s
order by "stof-dt"
fetch first 1 row only;
```

In MySQL, you would use `limit` instead of `fetch`.

In SQL Server, you would use one of:

```
select top (1)
```

or:

```
offset 0 row fetch first 1 row only
```

Comment: Thank you, the "offset 0 row fetch first 1 row only" works well :o). Now - one more question. This means that 1 row only will be displayed generally. Is there now any way to display this "MAX one row" per given ID in another column?

Comment: @Zdenek . . . This answers the question that you have asked here.  If you have another question, then ask as a *new* question, with sample data, desired results, and a clear explanation of the logic you want to implement.  However, you may find the answer you want online, if you search for something like "top row from group".